# SQL Server : get at the name of the app causing an update in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

We're trying to pinpoint the source of some unexpected updates happening on a SQL Server table. What I'd like to do is create a trigger on that table monitoring that column we're interested in, and when updates occur, write some audit info into a separate table.

Works great and fine for things like user name, date, old and new columns values (from the `Inserted` and `Deleted` trigger tables) - but I'd like more :-)

In SQL Profiler, you can see the name of the app that's connected to SQL Server in the profiles - the part that can be defined in the connection string as `Application Name`:

```
Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;
Integrated Security=True;Application Name="My Application"
```

Is there any way in a T-SQL `FOR UPDATE` trigger to get at this information?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
SELECT APP_NAME()
```

Comment: Sheeesh !! Can't be **that** easy, Martin!! ;-) I've been scouring all the `@@name` values and couldn't find anything......

Comment: @marc - You can also get it from `SELECT program_name from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_id=@@SPID` there might be other stuff in there of interest.

Comment: If you have multiple applications hitting a database and use auditing, this is a good thing to have as part of your audit tables. It has sure helped us track things down in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Marc_S the sP_whoIsActive stored Procedure probably will solve Your problems
[as posted here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/03/30/who-is-active-v8-40-now-with-delta-power.aspx)

and it's awesome part of T-SQL by the way

Comment: You've lost your link. I believe a new version has just come out (or is coming out very shortly) a link to a version is http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2010/10/21/who-is-active-v10-00-dmv-monitoring-made-easy.aspx

Comment: Link to latest and greatest beta version from Adam Machanic's twitter feed http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/beta/entry34124.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but could you possibly log the server name if you applications are on multiple servers? It might help narrow down the list of applications.

Comment: Thanks - but I really need the name of the app - this runs on a single database server, that name won't help me..